# Can I remove the unique constrain for error "Asset/Device with such name already exists."

Tags: thingsboard

We are using open source Thingsboard for our IOT platform. One project has 100K devices/assets, and we have a tree structure for the assets/devices for example state -> county -> city, etc. Each county, we have an administrator who is responsible for asset/device creation. Frequently they use the same name for asset or device. Currently, Thingsboard doesn't allow duplicated name for asset/device. If we use the same name, we will get error messages

> Asset with such name already exists

or

> Device with such name already exists

We are thinking to remove this unique constrain but not sure if there is any side effect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to remove the unique constraint, but there may be workarounds:

Make the names unique, e.g. by concating the structure in the Tree for unique names (State_County_City_Device) or use the Device ID as name. In the Dashboards you can utilize the Label Field for a friendly-name.

See issue here: https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/4439